# Jquery Mobile Not able to append to body

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, append

I would like to append the dynamically generated page to body but althought I dont see any error in console and not seeing the dynamic page on UI. What am I missing? once I get these, also I have multiple pages and all these pages are needed to be generated when I navigate through list items to those pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
 <title>Appstore</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>



<script src="js/chaseappstore.js"></script>




<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"
    />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chaseappstore.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">     </script>

<script>
if(/dy.htm/.test(window.location.href))
{
alert("h");

pg=CreatePageheader();
alert(pg);
$('body').append(pg);
alert("appended");

}


function CreatePageheader()
{
 alert('hh');
 pageDOM="<div id='LatestBuilds' data-role='page' data-transition='slide'   data-        cache='never' data-theme='aa'><div class='mFuturePageHeader chromeBar acb'  data-    role='header' data-tap-toggle='false' data-id='header' data-position='fixed'><table><tbody><tr><td class='left'><div  class='hidden' style=''><a  href='options.htm' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='slidedown'><img  src='images/logout_60x60_tp.png' class='hidden logoutButtonA' /></a></div><div class='hiddenshow'  style=''><a  href='javascript:ref()' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='slidedown'><img  src='images/Home.png' class=' hiddenshow logoutButtonA' /></a></div></td><td class='center mFuturePageHeaderTitle'>Chase Appstore - Latest Builds</td><td class='right'></td></tr></tbody></table></div>"
 pageDOM+="<div data-role='content'><div data-role='collapsible'data-theme='a' data-collapsed='false' data-content-theme='d'><h2>iPhone/iPod</h2><ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-inset='false' id='iPhoneCIG'></ul></div><div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='a' data-collapsed='false' data-content-theme='d'><h2>iPad</h2><ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true'  data-inset='false' id='iPadCIG'></ul></div><div data-role='collapsible'data-theme='a' data-collapsed='false' data-content-theme='d'><h2>Windows</h2><ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-inset='false' id='WindowsCIG'></ul></div><div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='a' data-collapsed='false' data-content-theme='d'><h2>Android</h2><ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true'  data-inset='false' id='AndroidCIG' ></ul></div></div>"
  pageDOM+="<div data-role='footer' data-id='footer' data-theme='a'  data-position='fixed'><div data-role='navbar'><ul><li><a href='#LatestProdBuilds'>Prod<br/>Links</a></li><li><a href='#LatestBuildsTSS'>TSS/<br/>WSS</a></li><li><a href='#LatestBuildsUR'><br/>CARD</a></li><li><a href='#' class='ui-btn-active ui-state-persist'>CIG/<br/>MEP</a></li><li><a href='#AllBuilds'>All<br/>Builds</a></li></ul></div></div></div>"



 return pageDOM;
} 



 </script>



</head>

<body class="body">  </body>




</html>
```

Comment: Try `$.mobile.pageContainer.append(page);`

Answer (score 0):

Omar was close, all you needed to do after that was change the page after it was appended to the page container. Also, give your code a good look over, remember to use var for your variables and you may want to consider using objects instead of super long strings when creating your page. Maybe run your javascript through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

Give this a go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
 <title>Appstore</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>



<script src="js/chaseappstore.js"></script>




<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"
    />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chaseappstore.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">     </script>

<script>

function load() {
    var pg = CreatePageheader();
    $.mobile.pageContainer.append(pg);
    $.mobile.changePage('#LatestBuilds');
}


function CreatePageheader()
{
 var pageDOM="<div id='LatestBuilds' data-role='page' data-transition='slide'   data-        cache='never' data-theme='aa'><div class='mFuturePageHeader chromeBar acb'  data-    role='header' data-tap-toggle='false' data-id='header' data-position='fixed'><table><tbody><tr><td class='left'><div  class='hidden' style=''><a  href='options.htm' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='slidedown'><img  src='images/logout_60x60_tp.png' class='hidden logoutButtonA' /></a></div><div class='hiddenshow'  style=''><a  href='javascript:ref()' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='slidedown'><img  src='images/Home.png' class=' hiddenshow logoutButtonA' /></a></div></td><td class='center mFuturePageHeaderTitle'>Chase Appstore - Latest Builds</td><td class='right'></td></tr></tbody></table></div>"
 pageDOM+="<div data-role='content'><div data-role='collapsible'data-theme='a' data-collapsed='false' data-content-theme='d'><h2>iPhone/iPod</h2><ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-inset='false' id='iPhoneCIG'></ul></div><div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='a' data-collapsed='false' data-content-theme='d'><h2>iPad</h2><ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true'  data-inset='false' id='iPadCIG'></ul></div><div data-role='collapsible'data-theme='a' data-collapsed='false' data-content-theme='d'><h2>Windows</h2><ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-inset='false' id='WindowsCIG'></ul></div><div data-role='collapsible' data-theme='a' data-collapsed='false' data-content-theme='d'><h2>Android</h2><ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true'  data-inset='false' id='AndroidCIG' ></ul></div></div>"
  pageDOM+="<div data-role='footer' data-id='footer' data-theme='a'  data-position='fixed'><div data-role='navbar'><ul><li><a href='#LatestProdBuilds'>Prod<br/>Links</a></li><li><a href='#LatestBuildsTSS'>TSS/<br/>WSS</a></li><li><a href='#LatestBuildsUR'><br/>CARD</a></li><li><a href='#' class='ui-btn-active ui-state-persist'>CIG/<br/>MEP</a></li><li><a href='#AllBuilds'>All<br/>Builds</a></li></ul></div></div></div>"



 return pageDOM;
} 



 </script>



</head>

<body class="body" onload="load()">  </body>




</html>
```